# Prototype .observe says attachEvent is not a function

Tags: jquery, prototype

Can somebody tells me, why do I get `attachEvent` is not a function error with this - [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lolka_bolka/Lwkmoekx/)?

```js
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

function myHandler() {
  alert('triggered');
}
Event.observe(j('#xxx'), 'change', myHandler);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.3/prototype.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="xxx" value="123" />
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using Prototype? It's last release was over 2.5 years ago. My point is that while it's entirely possible to diagnose this issue, it's better avoided, if possible.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, magento2 use it.

Comment: That's rather unfortunate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Event.observe()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/observe/) expects DOM element or id of the element so either pass `id` i.e. `xxx` directly or use [`.get(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/get/)/`[index]` get the reference to underlying DOM element at *index* and pass it to method.

```js
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

function myHandler() {
  console.log('triggered');
}
Event.observe('xxx', 'change', myHandler);
//Event.observe(j('#xxx').get(0), 'change', myHandler);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.3/prototype.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="xxx" value="123" />
```